# How make light ignore trasparent mesh

Tags: game-engine, transparency, hair

I trying to make mesh for hair  with transparency for BGE but the light is reflecting the entire model including the area that supposed to be invisible,the only way i find is unmark specular in the light, but i wish to find a better way because a want to use specular.[image]

Comment: Make the same texture affect the specular level

Answer (score 3):

You need to drag the **Specular Intensity** in the *Material* tab all the way down to zero. And enable **Intensity** under the *Specular* in the *Influence* tab of the texture, as seen below.

[image]